# UIPrintInteractionController Not Presenting Multiple Pages

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, uiprintinteractioncntrler

This issue has just appeared with iOS 13 and was not a problem prior. If I am presenting the `UIPrintInteractionController` controller with a single image, everything works fine. If I submit with more than one image, the print controller will not be displayed and instead I will get an error that states: `Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <UIViewController: 0x7fefcc4e7ab0> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!`

Below is the code in question. So again, if `printingItems` contains more than 1 element (which is the entire point of it), the controller won't display and the `success` portion of the completion handler will return `false`. Was not an issue in iOS 12.This is running on an iPad.

```
private func print(finalPageImages:[UIImage]) {
    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
    printInfo.jobName = "job name"
    printInfo.outputType = .general
    printInfo.duplex = .none
    printInfo.orientation = .landscape

    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
    printController.showsNumberOfCopies = false
    printController.printInfo = printInfo
    printController.printingItems = finalPageImages

    printController.present(from: self.printButton, animated: true) { (controller, success, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            Utilities.displayAlert(title: "Print Error", msg: error!.localizedDescription, controller: self)
            return
        }
        if success {
            Utilities.displayAlert(title: "Print Status", msg: "Your Shelf Talkers are printing.", controller: self, completion: { (action) in

            })
        } else {
            Utilities.displayAlert(title: "Print Error", msg: "There was a problem with this print job. Please try again.", controller: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to present the printController from the main thread using DispatchQueue async

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried that during my troubleshooting and it didn't change the result. Also, if that were the issue it wouldn't work with the print jobs that have 1 image either, but it does.

Comment: try declaring `printController` as a property of your view controller

Comment: Having the same issue, @C6Silver have you found workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue with multiple pdf files, so I just merged all the pdfs into one pdf and used

> printController.printingItem = mergeAllPdfs().dataRepresentation()

instead of

> printController.printingItems = [myPdf1.data, myPdf2.data, myPdf3.data]

Its a work around to solve the issue for now. Hope its helps.

```
func mergeAllPdfs() -> PDFDocument? {
    // get the first pdfData
    guard let firstPdf = allPDFs.first?.data, let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(data: firstPdf) else {
        return nil
    }
    // create new PDFDocument
    let newPdfDocument = PDFDocument()

    // insert all pages of first document
    for p in 0..<pdfDocument.pageCount {
        if let page = pdfDocument.page(at: p) {
            newPdfDocument.insert(page, at: newPdfDocument.pageCount)
        }
    }

    // loop for number of documents instead first one (which is allready added)
    for count in 1..<allPDFs.count {
        guard let nextPdfData = allPDFs[count].data, let nextPdf = PDFDocument(data: nextPdfData) else {
            return nil
        }
        for q in 0..<nextPdf.pageCount {  // all pages of a next document
            if  let page = nextPdf.page(at: q) {
                newPdfDocument.insert(page, at: newPdfDocument.pageCount)
            }
        }
    }
    return newPdfDocument
}
```